# What, exactly, is (estimation-theory)?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wikis

Disclaimer: I have no idea what estimation theory is about. But looking at [estimation-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimation-theory) I cannot help but think that either the tag means something extremely broad (so broad that I hesitate to think that there is a coherent underlying theory) or that some users are using the tag for things *other* than "estimation theory".

Perhaps related is the fact that we separately have the tags

- [estimation-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimation-theory)
- [approximation-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximation-theory)
- [estimation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimation)
- [approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximation)

**Question**: What are they and how are they related?

(For example: I have [some vague idea about what approximation theory is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory). Some of the questions currently tagged under that tag have absolutely no relation to the description on Wikipedia. I suspect we either have to dump a bunch into [approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximation) or create some new tags. Absent a good tag wiki, I think quite a few users just tag both (approximation) and (approximation-theory) when they don't know any better.)

Comment: I estimate that it is something approximately related to a theory.

Comment: Do mods have possibility to mass retag all questions from one tag to another, without causing bumping? (As opposed to making synonym.)

Comment: I've created some tag-wiki for [approximation-theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/approximation-theory/info) based on Wikipedia article. I hope someone with more knowledge about this area will improve the tag wiki.

Comment: @Martin: yes, mods can effectively rename tags by (ab)using the tag-merge feature (which also allows us to  merge one tag into another without creating a synonym). So your proposal below is technically feasible.

Comment: Tag-wiki for [estimation-theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/estimation-theory/info) was created by Ilmari Karonen.

Answer (score 7):

[Estimation Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_theory) is a branch of statistics.
[Approximation Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory) is a branch of real analysis.
I guess (estimation) and (approximation) are used in less precise senses.  Perhaps for estimates and approximations other than those specific ones in the first two.

Comment: are you guessing that, or is that your... estimation? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila - you are so witty :)

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

Estimation theory is the study of inverse problems arising from signal processing and is different from approximation theory. Broadly, given some random noise $\eta$ and observed signal $y$, one wishes to "solve" the equation
$$y=A(x)+\eta$$
for $x$ ("estimate" $x$). The main complication is that for many problems of practical interest, $A$ may not be 1-1, may not be onto, or if it is 1-1 and onto it may not have a continuous inverse. Dealing with these issues for $A$'s related to signal processing is what estimation theory is concerned with.

Mathematically, the two main methods of approaching the problem are

1. Deterministic: find $x$ that minimizes $||y-A(x)||$ in some suitable norm, where the norm may be related to the noise statistics, and
2. Probabilistic: Start with prior probability measures for $x$, $\eta$, and $y$, and then find an a posteriori probability probability measure for $x$ given $y$, such that all of the probability measures are related through some suitable infinite dimensional generalization of Bayes' theorem.

Comment: I went and added a tag wiki for [tag:estimation-theory], since it didn't have one yet. Since I don't really know anything about the topic, I just quoted [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_theory) (with proper attribution, of course), but feel free to improve or rewrite it.

Comment: I think the wikipedia summary is really fair. I tend to think of it more in terms solving an inverse problem, whereas statisticians think of it more in terms of finding unbiased estimators for a conditional random variable. The way it's written now leaves open both interpretations.

Comment: @NickAlger I would also add that under 'deterministic', there are also cases where you know 'truth', and so you want to minimize $||y - \hat{y}||$ where $y$ is truth, and $\hat{y}$ is your estimate. This is usually done for estimation of the matrix $\bf A$ via a training sequence.

Comment: Yeah definitely, though in that case I would consider the entries of $A$ to be parameters in a larger problem $y=B(A,x)+\eta$, $B(A,x):=Ax$.

Comment: The signal-processing meaning of "estimation theory" is a special case of the meaning in statistics.

Comment: The inverse problem perspective is more robust than you think. Given a statistical estimation problem, you can construct an inverse problem via the radon-nikodym derivative of the posterior with respect to the prior. To each statistical estimator, there corresponds an optimization problem. The signal processing usage, though, is more specialized.

Comment: There is a lot of overlap between signal processing and statistics, but it is incorrect to say that estimation theory "is" the signal-processing case (where, I think, the term was simply borrowed from older and more general use in statistics).  If the word "signal" is taken to mean arbitrary data then the two fields cover the same ground but I don't think this is what people ordinarily mean by the words.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I would agree with that.

Answer (score 2):

Estimation theory is a part of statistics.It comes under statistical Inference.
A sample from the distribution of a population is useful in making inferences about the population . The process of going from the known sample to the unknown population has been called statistical inference. Two important problems of Statistical inferences are (1)*Estimation* and (2)*Testing of Hypothesis*.

*ESTIMATION:* Some feature of the population in which an investigator is interested may be unknown to him and he may want to make a guess about this feature on the basis of a random sample drawn from the population. This type of problem is called the problem of *estimation*.
That's all I know about *Estimation.*

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this could help in deciding what to do with [approximation-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximation-theory) tag. We will see whether there are many questions which need retagging.
(BTW sorry for making 3 posts in the same question, I hope this thread is not too messy now.)

I've put here list of suggested retags of questions in this tag. The list is ordered from the oldest questions.
I've included only those questions where I trusted my judgement enough to make the call. The question is CW, feel free to edit it.

The list of the questions which are, at the moment, tagged [approximation-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximation-theory) can also be found [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5461464#5461464).

In case you make some of the suggested retags, please mark this by striking the corresponding line out. (It's good to keep the question in the list, so that we know how many of the original list of 30 questions have been dealt with.)

**Questions that should remain tagged [approximation-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximation-theory)**

- 3273: [Approximation theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3273/approximation-theorems)
- 12676: [What is "Approximation Theory"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12676/approximation-theory)
- 13854: [Error term when Lagrange interpolating continuous non-differentiable functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13854)
- 97628: [Distance from $x^n$ to lesser polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97628/distance-from-xn-to-lesser-polynomials)
- 114920: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114920/pade-approximant-of-the-logarithm
- 120510: [Books on Function approximation and Regression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120510/books-on-function-approximation-and-regression)
- 147311: [Generalizations of equi-oscillation criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147311)
- 153688: [Approximation of distribution in [0,1] by Beta density/Bernstein polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153688/approximation-of-distribution-in-0-1-by-beta-density-bernstein-polynomial)

**Questions that should be retagged [approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approximation)**

- <s>5568: [Why are some mathematical constants irrational by their continued fraction while others aren't?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/why-are-some-mathematical-constants-irrational-by-their-continued-fraction-while)</s>
- <s>80330: [Approximation of closest k-coloured points?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80330/approximation-of-closest-k-coloured-points)</s>
- <s>105204: [A better approximation of $H_n $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105204/a-better-approximation-of-h-n)</s>
- <s>138256: [Calculation of sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138256)</s>
- <s>140458: [asymptotic limit at the integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140458)</s>
- <s>140460: [Asymptotic limit of the integral with polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140460)</s>
- <s>141394: [asymptotic limit of $\int_0^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2(2k+3)}+\frac{t^4}{2\cdot 4\cdot(2k+3)\cdot(2k+5)}\right)^qdt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141394)</s>
- <s>157358: [is the approximation of the sum true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157358)</s>
- <s>163835: [errors, random and approximations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163835/errors-random-and-approximations)</s>
- <s>171929: [Approximate solution for the root of a non-linear function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171929/approximate-solution-for-the-root-of-a-non-linear-function) (Perhaps [numerical-methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods) would be appropriate for this question, too.)</s>

**Questions that should be retagged [spline](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spline)**

- <s>65597: [Cubic B-Spline (Basic Spline) Non-Zero Domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65597)</s>
- <s>125825: [Spline Theory and Code](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125825)</s>
- <s>143670: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143670</s>

**Other retags**

- <s>90179: [The flow/cut gap theorem for multicommodity flow](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90179/the-flow-cut-gap-theorem-for-multicommodity-flow)</s> would probably more appropriately tagged [algorithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms)
- <s>160867: [Why is there no alpha-approximation algorithms for k-center problem where alpha<2?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160867)</s> would probably more appropriately tagged [algorithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms)

**Not sure about proper tagging**

- 81115: [Approximation in the Plane of Constant Curvature](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81115)
- 110745: [An asymptotic approximation for exponential integrals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110745)
- 122229: [Compressed sensing, approximately sparse, Power law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122229)
- 150132: [integral with Bessel function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150132)
- 150454: [expansion of Hermite function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150454)
- 159180: [prove equality with integral and series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159180)
- 172479: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172479/covering-number-of-a-set-of-matrices

---

**NOTE:** I'll wait 2-3 days whether there are some objections against the retaggings I've suggested. Then I'll start to retag questions in a pace which (I hope) will not overfill the front page with old questions. I think tagging at most 4 questions every 6 hours seems reasonable. When I make a retag, I'll post a comment here and also in the [Tagging chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/3740/tagging), so that the retagging is somewhat coordinated if more users start working on this.

Comment: I've added also the questions, where I was not entirely sure about retagging. The list in this post should now contain all questions from [tag:approximation-theory] tag as of 2012/07/25. (If I did not make some mistake when compiling the list.)

Comment: Since we have tag [tag:spline], I think that the questions on spline should be retagged to this tag. Of course, if you disagree with these sugested retags, feel free to edit my post.

Comment: I've made the retags suggested in this post. It was quite a few retags for one day, but I tried to leave a few hours between each batch. I hope that old posts which were bumped did not bother MSE users too much.

Comment: Perhaps I might add that after my retagging 15 questions remained tagged [tag:approximation-theory].